# Using enzyme, How to find a child component in a component react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, enzyme

I am new to React-native and enzyme, I am trying to create a custom component here.
I will be displaying an Image based on `this.props.hasIcon`. I set default props value for `hasIcon` as `true`. When I check `Image` exists in enzyme ShallowWrapper. I am getting `false`.

`tlProgress.js`

```
class TLProgress extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderImage}
        {this.renderProgress}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

TLProgress.defaultProps = {
  icon: require("./../../img/logo.png"),
  indeterminate: true,
  progressColor: Colors.TLColorAccent,
  hasIcon: true,
  progressType: "bar"
};
```

and `renderImage()` has the `Image`

```
renderImage() {
    if (this.props.hasIcon) {
      return <Image style={styles.logoStyle} source={this.props.icon} />;
    }
}
```

Now, If I check `Image` exists in enzyme am getting false.

`tlProgress.test.js`

```
describe("tlProgress rendering ", () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeAll(() => {
        props = { indeterminate: false };
        wrapper = shallow(<TLProgress {...props} />);
    });

    it("check progress has app icon", () => {
        expect(wrapper.find("Image").exists()).toBe(true); // fails here..
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling the renderImage function in your render() -- you forgot the brackets, thus it is being interpreted as an undefined variable.

It should be: (I am assuming you want to call renderProgress() and not renderProgress as well)

```
class TLProgress extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.renderImage()}
        {this.renderProgress()}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're searching for a tag called 'Image' instead of looking for your component Image

It should be :

```
import Image from '../Image';
wrapper.find(Image) //do your assert here
```

Comment: `expect(wrapper.find(Image).exists()).toBe(true);` is giving me `false`.. it is failing..

Comment: @user2906641 try replacing shallow with mount

Comment: ya I tried that first, I got error `Enzyme's mount expects a DOM environment to be loaded, but found none`.. Then I used shallow.

Comment: @user2906641 Can you log the find statement? I’m not sure wether exists works for components

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

      at Object.<anonymous> (app/components/res/__test__/tlProgress.test.js:22:15)
      at tryCallTwo (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
      at doResolve (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
      at new Promise (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
      at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
      at node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:123:15

Comment: Enzyme's mount expects a DOM environment to be loaded, but found none

      at assertDomAvailable (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-utils/build/Utils.js:107:11)
      at ReactSixteenAdapter.createMountRenderer (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:199:52)
      at ReactSixteenAdapter.createRenderer (node_modules/enzyme-adapter-react-16/build/ReactSixteenAdapter.js:380:25)
      at new ReactWrapper (node_modules/enzyme/build/ReactWrapper.js:96:54)
      at mount (node_modules/enzyme/build/mount.js:19:10)

Comment: at Object.<anonymous> (app/components/res/__test__/tlProgress.test.js:10:26)
      at tryCallTwo (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
      at doResolve (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)

Comment: Is your testEnvironment set to jsdom?

Comment: how to test that? how to setup jsdom test environment?